# Where do i trace NVME IO within the Linux driver?

Tags: kernel, drivers, c, nvme

I want to write a small Linux driver extension. More specific: I want to write all the communication between the host and a M.2-nvme-ssd into a userspace file. The nvme driver is pretty big though and i have difficulties pinpointing some place to start at.

A colleague of mine has done something similar for SD cards. He traced the IO after the host has received the response from the card and is about to wrap up the operation (the function is `sdhci_request_done`). The trace shows requests and responses with opcode, data and timestamps. Something like this would be my goal.

I have found programs that trace IO, but they operate in userspace. That is a problem, as i might send a message to the card directly from the driver.

So my question is: Where do i tap into the host-driver to get the data, without delaying the operations or allocating much memory. Or is there a driver-function that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A colleague of mine has done something similar for SD cards. He traced the IO after the host has received the response from the card and is about to wrap up the operation (the function is sdhci_request_done).

Unlike SD cards, most data will actually be exchanged via DMA to an nvme device (usually), so your Linux can't know the content of the transfer, only that it happened. I'm sure you can disable DMA, to huge performance reduction. I don't know how to do that, but you can possibly achieve it using a kernel boot flag.

Other than that, you can already trace all commands exchanged, without having to extend anything. Linux has tracepoints, and nvme is just one family of them; so

```bash
sudo perf trace -e nvme:nvme_\* > logfile
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the quick reply. I sadly can only test this next week, but I looked it up and I am sure this is part of what i need. I will accept the answer afterwards. An additional question though, i thought SD cards use DMA. And there still has to be some pointer to the data that is sent right? So if i just provide a pointer to a memory block in kernel space, it should be possible to read it?

Comment: Well, strictly speaking it needs to be the interface between you SD card and your CPU that needs to do DMA, and most SD card readers can't, because they are not connected via DMA-capable interfaces (typically, USB).

Comment: "there still has to be some pointer to the data that is sent right?" yes."So if i just provide a pointer to a memory block in kernel space, it should be possible to read it?" The memory might be directly read into a userland buffer, so there's not necessarily a kernel address to it.